# Show HTML file contained within the extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm creating a website blocker: after you visit a website you've blocked, the browser displays a new HTML page saying "website blocked". The new HTML page is saved in my Chrome extension as *message.html*. Is there any way to display *message.html* in the browser? If not, I'll just use a content script to inject some JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updating a tab to display *message.html*

Assuming all of the following are true:

- You are doing this from a script running in the background context.
- You are wanting to update an already existing tab to display *message.html*
- The ID tab which you are wanting to update is `tabId`.
- Your *message.html* is located in the same directory as your *manifest.json*.

You could do the following, which uses [`chrome.tabs.update()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) ([Firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/update)) to change the tab with the ID contained in `tabId` to display your *message.html*:

```js
chrome.tabs.update(tabId ,{url:'/message.html'});
```

or

```js
chrome.tabs.update(tabId ,{url:chrome.runtime.getURL('/message.html'}));
```

If you are changing the currently selected tab in the active window, then the `tabId` is not required, and you can omit that argument.

### Create a tab to display *message.html*

Assuming all of the following are true:

- You are doing this from a script running in the background context.
- You are wanting to create a new tab to display *message.html*
- Your *message.html* is located in the same directory as your *manifest.json*.

You can use [`chrome.tabs.create()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) ([Firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create)) to create a new tab to display *message.html*:

```js
chrome.tabs.create({url:'/message.html'});
```

or

```js
chrome.tabs.create({url:chrome.runtime.getURL('/message.html'}));
```

### Open *message.html* in a new window

Assuming all of the following are true:

- You are doing this from a script running in the background context.
- You are wanting to create a new window to display *message.html*
- Your *message.html* is located in the same directory as your *manifest.json*.

You can use [`chrome.windows.create()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) ([Firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create)) to open a new window to display *message.html*:

```js
chrome.windows.create({url:'/message.html'});
```

or

```js
chrome.windows.create({url:chrome.runtime.getURL('/message.html'}));
```