# How can I create a persistent extension page?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is it possible to make the browserAction popup persistent so that it's not reloaded every time? Failing that, is it possible to have any viewable extension page that can be hidden instead of closed?

I have a complex layout involving a large number of elements that I'm currently saving and loading as a string or using importNode to work around the issue but neither option is great.

Comment: Just open it in a tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not cause an actual `browserAction` or `pageAction` popup to persist. However, just like any HTML page in your extension, you can [open that HTML page in either a tab or window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837213/show-html-file-contained-within-the-extension).

As to hiding an extension page: A tab does not need to be currently viewed. A window displaying the HTML page could be hidden by minimizing the window you desire to hide. Alternately, you could placed the window you desire to hide under another window by bringing the other window into focus. A third option would be to move the to-be-hidden window to coordinates that are off the screen. All of these are accomplished with [`windows.update()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/update).

Comment: Thanks. I see what you're suggesting but those are very hack solutions, so I'll take it as a no.